# how to correct word rotate - ly?

Tags: word-request

I want to say a group of people can be host rotate. Means if there's four of us, me can be host today and guest 'A' can be host tomorrow and then 'B' can be host at day 3 ... I will be host again at day 5.

I sense it may be **rotate - ly** or something similar? how do I say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "rotate" is a verb.  You have to use it as a verb

> The host will rotate with each meeting.

There is a little ambiguity, because this could also mean "The host will pirouette". The context makes it clear.

You can use the phrase "in rotation", which can function like a -ly word.

> The host will be chosen in rotation.

Comment: "also me" at line 3 should be "also mean" as my understand.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. You are correct.

Comment: @JamesK Hi! I always upvote your good answers and the system reversed. My upvotes dissappeared!That is unfair!

Comment: That is because it is called "serial voting" and is not allowed by the system.